# Jquery получить значение height из стилей

Tags: jquery

Пример:

```
$(el).css("height");
```

не подходит, так как он получает просто размер высоты окна.
Нужно получить именно значение из стилей. То есть в стилях указано именно `height: calc(100vh - 49px);` а скрипт возвращает просто размер блока в px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, примерно так:

```js
$(function() {
  var ss = document.styleSheets[0];
  var rules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
  var h1Rule = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var rule = rules[i];
    if (/(^|,) *h1 *(,|$)/i.test(rule.selectorText)) {
      h1Rule = rule;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(h1Rule.style.height)

});
```

```css
h1
{
    height: calc(100vh - 49px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это типа парсера? Он много памяти занимает? У меня скрипт очень большой и стилей подключено много на странице, а так же неизвестна их очередность.

Comment: Нет, это просто перебор по используемым данным

Comment: спасибо большое, Вы профи)

Comment: Единственное, если у вас несколько похожих селекторов, он будет искать только в первом найденном. Т.е. в этом случае надо будет доработать код

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз дорабатываю. Главное, что уже хоть знаю куда плясать.