# Почему возвращает значения RGB каналов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Добрый день уважаемые. Столкнулся с не пониманием почему JS возвращает значения RGB каналов хотя в CSS задаю под HSL. В целом задача состоит такая- необходимо каждые две секунды менять значения цветов у квадратов. Первый и второй блоки (столбци) квадратов должны получать +10 к hue каналу каждые две секунды ( То есть после второй секунды у классов .first_st* должны быть значения h =11 а у классов .second_st* = 21 ). 
Если значения h доходят до 360 то добавляется сколько возможно а затем всё стартует с нуля. (То есть на 36 итерации у классов .first_st* должны быть значения h =1 а у классов .second_st* = 11)
Приведу код:

```js
 var allFirstColors = $("[class^='first_st']"),
  firstColorsLength = allFirstColors.length,

  allSecondColors = $("[class^='second_st']"),
  secondColorsLength = allFirstColors.length;

 var h,s,l;

  console.log(" st1 = " + $(".first_st1").css("fill") ); // Почему возвращает RGB каналы? 

  allFirstColors.each(function(indx, el){
    let  color = $(el).css("fill"),
    [h,s,l] = color.match(/\d+/g);
 console.log("[h,s,l] = " + [h,s,l]);
  });
```

```css
.first_st1{
   fill: hsl(1, 50%, 50%);
  }
  .first_st2{
   fill: hsl(1, 70%, 40%);
  }
  .first_st3{
   fill: hsl(1, 90%, 30%);
  }

  .second_st1{
   fill: hsl(11, 50%, 50%);
  }
  .second_st2{
   fill: hsl(11, 70%, 40%);
  }
  .second_st3{
   fill: hsl(11, 90%, 30%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="240">
  <rect class="first_st1" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="0"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st2" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="80"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st3" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="160"></rect>

  <rect class="second_st1" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="0"></rect>
  <rect class="second_st2" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="80"></rect>
  <rect class="second_st3" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="160"></rect>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Таков api, придётся конвертировать.

Answer (score 1):

После вашего вопроса, я заинтересовался и начал усиленно гуглить.

`$(el).css()` по сути возвращает вам свойства из `getComputedStyle(el)`, а `getComputedStyle(el)` возвращает высчитанные(resolved) свойства, т.е. браузеры сами конвертируют ваш цвет в rgb(a) и возвращают его и работать с тем что вы написали у вас не получиться, поэтому придется конвертировать вручную в нужный вам формат.
Например если выставить `width:100%;`, то getComputedStyle вернет вам длину блока в px, а не 100%.

Вот ниже нашел функцию которая по формуле из вики конвертирует rgba в hsl.

```js
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}

console.log(rgbToHsl(191, 66, 63));
```

Только вам придется доп. округлять

Answer (score 1):

Даже если обратиться напрямую к стилям (что в [некоторых случаях работает хорошо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612954/223191)), невозможно никаким образом получить ни `hex`, ни `hsl` значения. Только специальное обозначение типа "`red`":

```js
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if (classes[x].selectorText == className) {
            (classes[x].style.cssText) ? console.log(classes[x].style.cssText) : console.log(classes[x].cssText);
        }
    }
}
getStyle('.first_st1');
getStyle('.first_st2');
getStyle('.first_st3');
```

```css
.first_st1 {
  fill: red;
}
.first_st2 {
  fill: #ff5555;
}
.first_st3 {
  fill: hsl(1, 90%, 30%);
}
.second_st1 {
  fill: hsl(11, 50%, 50%);
}
.second_st2 {
  fill: hsl(11, 70%, 40%);
}
.second_st3 {
  fill: hsl(11, 90%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="240">
  <rect class="first_st1" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="0"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st2" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="80"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st3" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="160"></rect>

  <rect class="second_st1" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="0"></rect>
  <rect class="second_st2" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="80"></rect>
  <rect class="second_st3" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="160"></rect>
</svg>
```

Поэтому, хорошим способом решить проблему будет использование [`data-*`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) тегов:

```js
var allFirstColors = $("[class^='first_st']"),
  firstColorsLength = allFirstColors.length;

var h, s, l;

console.log(" st1 = " + $(".first_st1").css("fill"));

allFirstColors.each(function(indx, el) {
  let color = $(el).data("hsl"),
    [h, s, l] = color.match(/\d+/g);
  console.log("[h,s,l] = " + [h, s, l]);
});
```

```css
.first_st1 {
  fill: hsl(1, 50%, 50%);
}
.first_st2 {
  fill: hsl(1, 70%, 40%);
}
.first_st3 {
  fill: hsl(1, 90%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="240">
  <rect class="first_st1" data-hsl="1, 50, 50" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="0"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st2" data-hsl="1, 70, 40" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="80"></rect>
  <rect class="first_st3" data-hsl="1, 90, 30" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="160"></rect>


</svg>
```

С помощью `$(el).data("hsl")` получите hsl данные, затем запишите измененные с помощью `$(el).data("hsl", h+', '+s+', '+l)`

Comment: Что то не получается получить данные window.onload = function(){

 var allFirstColors = $("[class^='first_st']"),
  firstColorsLength = allFirstColors.length,

  allSecondColors = $("[class^='second_st']"),
  secondColorsLength = allFirstColors.length;

 var h,s,l;

  allFirstColors.each(function(indx, el){
  
  let  color = $(el).data("fill");
  $(el).data("hsl", h+', '+s+', '+l);

  console.log("color = " + color );

  }); 
} Да, и в документации прописывают что  методы .data(key) и .data(), вы получите значение переменных только у первого элемента из всех выбранных.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 `$(el).data("hsl");` hsl, a не fill.  `hsl` соответствует названию атрибута  `data-hsl="1, 90, 30"` вы можете выбрать любое название `data-color` `data-fill`

Comment: Не, записывать в html вообще не вариант. Тут простой пример в 6 квадратиков. В реальности ж мне необходимо работать с полигонами и их > 100

Comment: @BlackStar1991 data-* атрибуты хорошо масштабируются. Поэтому я рекомендовал их.

Answer (score 0):

Посоветовали реализовать мою задумку через перебор

```js
window.onload = function(){
  
    var initialH1 = 1
        initialH2 = 11,
        allFirstColors = $("[class^='first_st']"),
        firstColorsLength = allFirstColors.length,
        allSecondColors = $("[class^='second_st']"),
        secondColorsLength = allFirstColors.length;
          
    window.setInterval(function(){
  
        initialH1 = initialH1 === 360 ? 1 : initialH1 + 10 < 360 ? initialH1 + 10 : 360;
        initialH2 = initialH2 === 360 ? 11 : initialH2 + 10 < 360 ? initialH2 + 10 : 360;
          
        allFirstColors.each(function(i){
            $(this).css("fill", `hsl(${initialH1}, ${50 + i * 10}%, ${50 - i * 10}%)`);
 
            console.log( $(this).css("fill") + " = first block" )
        })
          
        allSecondColors.each(function(i){
            $(this).css("fill", `hsl(${initialH2}, ${50 + i * 10}%, ${50 - i * 10}%)`);
 
            console.log( $(this).css("fill") + " = second block" )
 
        })
          
    }, 2000)
}
```

```css
   .first_st1{
            fill: hsl(1, 50%, 50%);
        }
        .first_st2{
            fill: hsl(1, 70%, 40%);
        }
        .first_st3{
            fill: hsl(1, 90%, 30%);
        }
  
        .second_st1{
            fill: hsl(11, 50%, 50%);
        }
        .second_st2{
            fill: hsl(11, 70%, 40%);
        }
        .second_st3{
            fill: hsl(11, 90%, 30%);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="240">
        <rect class="first_st1" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="0"></rect>
        <rect class="first_st2" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="80"></rect>
        <rect class="first_st3" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="160"></rect>
  
        <rect class="second_st1" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="0"></rect>
        <rect class="second_st2" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="80"></rect>
        <rect class="second_st3" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="160"></rect>
    </svg>
```

В принципе оно работает, но меня не очень устраивает. Как быть если Значения в блоках совершенно разные, как прописать алгоритм ? Допустим для таких значений ?

```css
.first_st1{
            fill: hsl(1, 84%, 61%);
        }
        .first_st2{
           fill: hsl(358, 83%, 54%);
        }
        .first_st3{
            fill: hsl(350, 65%, 40%);
        }
  
        .second_st1{
            fill: hsl(11, 84%, 61%);
        }
        .second_st2{
            fill: hsl(8, 83%, 54%);
        }
        .second_st3{
            fill: hsl(0, 65%, 40%);
        }
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="240">
        <rect class="first_st1" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="0"></rect>
        <rect class="first_st2" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="80"></rect>
        <rect class="first_st3" width="80" height="80" x="0" y="160"></rect>
  
        <rect class="second_st1" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="0"></rect>
        <rect class="second_st2" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="80"></rect>
        <rect class="second_st3" width="80" height="80" x="160" y="160"></rect>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Вы отвечаете на свой вопрос или даете уточнение? Если даете уточнение, тогда надо править вопрос, а не писать ответ